# The meaning of " He managed to cling on to a ledge 40ft down the rock face..."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have looked up "down" in the Collins Dictionary. There is one example which makes me confused:

> He managed to cling on to a ledge 40ft down the rock face...

What does ***rock face*** and ***ledge*** mean? I haven't climbed the rock before , so I have no concept of these two words.Can you find a photo which can illustrate them?

Answer (score 4):

Ledge is a narrow horizontal surface projecting from a wall, cliff, or other surface. (Source: [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=bare%20vertical%20surface&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs#channel=rcs&q=LEDGE&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&safe=off))

[image]

Rock face means a bare vertical surface of natural rock. (Source: [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=rock+face&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs#channel=rcs&q=rock+face+meaning&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&safe=off))

[image]

Comment: Note that "down" is being used just to describe the location of the ledge (it is 40 feet down). It has nothing to do with the clinging.

Comment: Here's a climber standing on a cliff ledge: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/picturegalleries/8715942/Extreme-rock-climber-Alex-Honnold-tackles-cliff-faces-around-the-globe.html?image=2